# React-native animate component when it is visible on viewport

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

I have a component which is in the second page of the screen. How do I animate this component, only when it is visible in the viewport in Reactive?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? i am running into same issue. I want to animate list item when its visible on screen